# cannot send otp sms from twilio to non verified user even after upgrade

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, one-time-password

Cant send sms otp to non verified number.Have upgraded the service and still not recieving the otp . Code seems fine and do work in verififed number

Comment: Can you share the code you are using? Are you getting an error when you try to send the message? Do you have the right [Geographic permissions](https://www.twilio.com/console/sms/settings/geo-permissions) set up for sending SMS messages?

Comment: thank you . i have to make a sender id for country , they said it was blocking my otp. now it is fine after senderid was verified